# Conectar Wise-4051 a Base de datos

Tags: php, python, json, webservice

Tengo un dispositivo Wise-4051, quiero saber como podria conectarlo a una base de datos, hasta ahorita solo puedo exportar a excel y se guarda en Google Drive, lo que planeo hacer es conectarlo a una base de datos, usado web service.

Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Qué es Wise-4051? - [edit] su respuesta para incluir toda la información que una persona necesite para entender su problema. Además, añade el código y/o lo que ha investigado.

Comment: Conectarlo a una BD usando un web service? Es decir, no conectarlo sino integrarlo con una capa intermedia. Aún así, no sabemos a qué base de datos, con qué web service y en qué lenguaje (porque refieres dos en las etiquetas)